# Dynamic Rules creation with any java rule engine

Tags: rule-engine

I have this question and trying to get suggestions ,i am working on a a project where the business admins go to UI and sets some rules ..For example lets say JIRA has a feature like if this jiraticket belongs to (Some arbitrary board "XYZ" ) board and type of the jira is "Task" then Label should be added ..

This kind of rules the admin of JIRA  through the admin screens  sets this rules(How he sets it keep it a side for now )...Now when the user creates a JIRA under the board and sets type with our Lable then based on the rule it should throw an error saying the label should be set ..

There are two parts to implement this feature

1)While admin sets this through the screen we need to create the rule and store it some where..
2)While user creates the jira run the rules which has been stored and say it is valid or not

I am looking for any framework in java it can be done easily for 1) which creates the rule where some framework can understans it and can run the riles with  2) point.

Does some one has any suggestions on this ..?

Thanks,
Swati